# Quicktime won't play videos in Chrome

Tags: mac, google-chrome, quicktime, plugins

So, I was just trying to watch some video online in Chrome, and when I get to the page I'm told I "need to install Quicktime to play the video". This is odd because I clearly have Quicktime in my applications on my Mac. It seems to be a Chrome problem, but I've read I should go to chrome:plugins and make sure it's on there; Quicktime does not appear on that list. It DOES appear under "Extensions", where it says it's enabled, but still nothing.

When I click the little dropdown box that says I need Quicktime to watch the video, I'm just taken to a page that tells me "Quicktime comes with Mac" with no apparent link to download it independently.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: so what is the web site you are having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 39 Chrome is now 64 bit only but there is only a 32 bit version of the QuickTime plug in. I do not think a workaround currently exists other than using another browser, Safari being your best bet for compatibility.

Source - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6510828

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has disabled many plug-ins including QuickTime in its latest release.

Actually, I believe this is due to the fact that Chrome 39+ is 64-bit and the QuickTime player plugin is 32-bit.